# Filtro de Coluna em DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

Boa Tarde,

Estou iniciando em python e tambem aqui no Stack.
fiz algumas pesquisas, mas acredito que minha falta de experiência não esteja permitindo filtrar de forma adequada o que necessito.

supondo um DF de 5 linhas e 3 colunas, preenchidos apenas com 0 e 1 (representação visual):
ABC
1 000
2 101
3 100
4 011
5 001

eu gostaria de chamar por exemplo, somente os valores '1' da coluna "A", não a coluna inteira como em :
filtro = df[['A']]
print(filtro)

*o grande porém é que me foi solicitado fazer isso com notação abreviada em indexação lógica.*

Peço desculpas se a exemplificação ficar ruim.
Agradeço de antemão a todos.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode filtrar linhas à partir de colunas usando o `.loc`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0,1,1,0,0],
    'B': [0,0,0,1,0],
    'C': [0,1,0,1,1],
})

filtrados = df.loc[df['A'] == 1]

print(filtrados)
```

Saída:

```
   A  B  C
1  1  0  1
2  1  0  0
```

ou pegar a Série da coluna A:

```py
colunaA = df.loc[df['A'] == 1, 'A']

print(colunaA)
```

Saída:

```
1  1 
2  1
```